# How can I join points with line in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I've 4 points. I want to join first two of the with a line and then second two with another line
My desired picture is given below

[image: Plots]

I can draw the first graph with maker. but but I want to join these points.

Answer (score 2):

You can plot them by listing the various different lines in (X,Y) sets one after another in one use of `plot`.

```
plot([a(1) a(2)],[b(1) b(2)],[a(3) a(4)],[b(3) b(4)])
```